# Transparent JLabels on a JLayeredPane

Tags: swing, png, jlabel, bufferedimage, jlayeredpane

I am trying to display several PNG Images on a JLayeredPane with overlapping.

Here is the current code for generating the JLabel containing the image and adding it to the JLayeredPane :

```
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new File(fname));
JLabel uLabel = createLabelForImage(im);
mapLayeredPane.add(uLabel, new Integer(zIndex++), 1);
```

And the createLabelForImage() method :

```
protected JLabel createLabelForImage(BufferedImage im) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(im));
    label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBounds(0, 0, im.getWidth(), im.getHeight());

    return label;
}
```

What I get is the objects are correctly overlapping but the transparent background of the PNG images is replaced with a kind of white-gray color.

Is it a problem with ImageIcon ? With JLayeredPane ? Maybe I have to set something like label.setBakground(sort_of_transparency_code) or something like that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label should not be opaque if you want to see through, see JComponent.setOpaque

```
 If true the component paints every pixel within its bounds. 
 Otherwise, the component may not paint some or all of its
 pixels, allowing the underlying pixels to show through.
```

Comment: Right, it was it ! The setOpaque() was put here during tests because JLabels did not display at all at first time... I had forgotten about this line... much better now. Thank you very much :) .